# Extract JSON Value from Table

Tags: json, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I have a MariaDB table called genres with these columns (genres is a JSON column):

```
+----+------------------------------------+
| id | genres                             |
+----+------------------------------------+
| 1  | ["Action", "Martial Arts", "Love"] |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

If I query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT( (SELECT genres.genres FROM genres), '$[2]' );
```

I get:

```
"Love"
```

Which is correct. But if I try to use the JSON_EXTRACT() shortcut arrow operator, -> :

```
SELECT genres.genres->"$[2]" FROM genres;
```

I get:

**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>"$[1]" FROM genres' at line 1**

Why can't I use the arrow operator? Is something wrong with my syntax or data? Why does it only work when I do it the long way, with JSON_EXTRACT()?

Comment: Where did you read/see the "short" way being valid?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path Does it work in MariaDB too?

Comment: This link is not an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why not? It has many examples of using the JSON -> operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*column* **->** *path* and *column* **->>** *path* operators are not supported in MariaDB-10.2, 10.3 even in 10.4 yet.

This might be shorter version for your case

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT( genres , '$[2]' ) FROM genres
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for suggesting the shorter version. It'll do until MariaDB supports -> and ->>.

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13594

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#incompatibilities-between-currently-unsupported-mariadb-versions-and-mysql

Aaa not priority for themm..